# Is this sentence using the word 'zugewandt' correct?

Tags: translation

I was reading a German blog and I found a sentence that looked incorrect to me, but I am not sure.

The sentence is:

> Eine kostengünstige Alternative, um das Stadtpanorama zu genießen, ist
>   der Besuch des Pylon Lookouts **im der Stadt gewandten Turm der
>   Brücke**

I assumed that this was a typo and it should say 'im Stadt gewandten Turm' with 'Stadt gewandten' acting as an adjective. Is that correct? Do you simply use 'gewandt' in the meaning of 'facing' by putting a noun in front of it, like 'Ich fand einen Meer gewandten Hügel'?

Danke im Voraus!

Comment: As others already suggested the [blog](https://wetraveltheworld.de/sydney-sehenswuerdigkeiten-tipps/) says "ist der Besuch des Pylon Lookouts im der Stadt **zu**gewandten Turm der Brücke."

Answer (score 3):

`im der Stadt gewandten Turm der Brücke` - It should be `in dem der Stadt zugewandten Turm der Brücke`. So if you just forgot the "zu" you wrote about in the title, it'd be ok. "in dem" makes the sentence clearer, but "im" would also be ok.

Answer (score 3):

There should be a "zu" somewhere, maybe it was omitted, or maybe you just forgot to type it, as the title says "**zu**gewandt".

> im zur Stadt gewandten Turm der Brücke
>
> im der Stadt zugewandten Turm der Brücke

The meaning is that the bridge has more than one tower, and at least one of them is facing the town. There must be more than one tower, because otherwise it doesn't make sense to specify which tower, but that doesn't follow from the structure of the sentence.

In "im Stadt gewandten Turm" there is even more omitted, but it would still be understandable, so it might be used in a poem where the rhythm is more important than proper grammar.

Comment: In terms of the two towers thing, could it not be that the writer was simply being descriptive by describing the tower as facing the city, and also stressing that you can get a panorama of the City from it?

Comment: It is possible, but I wouldn't use it that way. Do you know whether there is more than one tower?

Comment: It is Sydney Harbour Bridge, and it looks like there are multiple towers. Cannot confirm if they all face the city in order to give a panorama, but the reading the sentence again I definitely understand what you mean.

Comment: Adjectives need not be restrictive: *der große Turm* can be used to distinguish two towers, or to characterise a single tower.

Answer (score 2):

> **Original**: Eine kostengünstige Alternative, um das Stadtpanorama zu genießen, ist der Besuch des Pylon Lookouts *im der Stadt gewandten Turm* der Brücke.

You are right that there is something wrong with this sentence. But it's more than just the incorrect phrase italicized.

1. The *um ... zu* construction is not correct, because the (implicit) subject of the subordinate clause differs from the subject of the main clause (see, e. g., [Canoonet](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Komplex/Funktion/Adverbial/Final.html?lang=en)). The subordinate clause should instead be an ordinary infinitive with *zu*.
2. In German, *Pylon-Lookout* is a single word, which is why it should be hyphenated.
3. It must be *zugewandt* (from [zuwenden](https://www.dwds.de/wb/zuwenden)) instead of *gewandt* (from [wenden](https://www.dwds.de/wb/wenden)).
4. For stylistic reasons, I would put more emphasis on the genitive *der Stadt* by writing *in dem der Stadt* rather than *im der Stadt*.

To summarize:

> **Amended:** Eine kostengünstige Alternative, *<s>um</s>* das Stadtpanorama zu genießen, ist der Besuch des Pylo*n-L*ookouts *in dem <s>im</s>* der Stadt *zu*gewandten Turm der Brücke.

Comment: 1. is mistaken on two counts. Firstly, the rule is false: *doch Kenia ist viel zu schön und interessant, um nur am Strand zu liegen* or *beispielsweise wird ein Apfel gekauft, um ein Image von Gesundheitsbewußtsein zu erwerben*. Secondly, the construction in question is attached to a noun, which cannot have a a subject. Another example: *Internetplattformen sind schon **eine Hilfe, um sich zu präsentieren.***

Comment: https://learngerman.dw.com/de/finals%C3%A4tze-um-zu-1/l-40606838/gr-40608964

Comment: @DavidVogt I am not convinced. Susanne ist vielleicht viel zu schön, um am Strand zu liegen (statt in meinem Bett), aber was soll Kenia in meinem Bett? It is very close to a *Stilblüte.* In the second example the actors are identical.